# Extjs 4 How to merge 2 similar records into one record

Tags: extjs4.1

I have Grid, where I want to merge similar records into one record.

I don't want to Group record, I want to Merge record

I mean,

```
{
{
firstField: "record1",
commonField: "ABC",
fourthField: "4"
},
{
firstField: "record2",
commonField: "ABC",
fourthField: "5"
},
{
firstField: "record3",
commonField: "ABC",
fourthField: "6"
}
}
```

So this the above JSON u can see there is "commonField" which has similar text.
So I have to show 1 record instead of 3 records, with FourthField added [4+5+6] so my final JSON should become like

```
{
{
firstField: "record1",
commonField: "ABC",
fourthField: "15"
}
```

}

Is there any way to achieve this ? like summary we do addition or some operation 
similar can we do on Records ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a turnkey solution for this. You'll have to create some logic to generate new records based on old records that have the same commonField values, then destroy the old records.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, I guess I need to write some custom code only.

Comment: this is better handled on the server.